# Powershell 2.0 SecurityProtocolType vs Slack webhook

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, slack-api

UPDATE: In the end I was allowed to install Powershell 3 which gave me access to the Invoke-WebRequest module. I did not end up needing to update .Net framework or change the registry to enforce encryption protocols, which are still valid solutions if anyone should find themselves in a similar situation.

I'm trying to hit my Slack webhook from an environment where I am forced to use Powershell 2.0. The Slack server is not liking either of the available Net.SecurityProtoType types available (ssl3 or tls). I have confirmed from the Slack documentation that tls 1.2 or higher is required [here](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2019-07-deprecate-early-tls-versions). I get an error message:

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
```

```
$PAYLOAD = @{"text" = "Slack message text"}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::tls
$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://hooks.slack.com/services/")
$WebRequest.Method = "POST"
$WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($PAYLOAD)
$WebRequest.ContentLength = $bytes.Length

$Stream = [System.IO.Stream]$WebRequest.GetRequestStream()
$Stream.write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
```

Notes: The URL is correct. It works in environments with newer versions of Powershell.

The Version of .Net is 4.0. I don't think we can update this. There are ways to acquire tls 1.2 in .Net 4.0 according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) document but I am very unsure of the risks of modifying protocols in the registry...

Much of this code is from what I found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535218/how-to-correctly-send-json-data-via-net-webrequest-powershell) post after I realized Invoke-WebRequest was not going to happen. I suspect there is a chance that I may be encoding my JSON incorrectly, but I also do not have access to the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet that they used there.

Thanks for reading! This is a very tough one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which security protocol types/versions are available on your system, you can execute:

```bsh
[enum]::GetNames([System.Net.SecurityProtocolType])
```

Fortunately, the result does not depend on your PowerShell version. So you don't have to upgrade PowerShell to a newer version, if `Tls12` is not available, for example. But you have to upgrade your .NET framework at least to 4.5 to get `Tls12`. You are probably using an older version than 4.5. To find out, which version you have installed, you can use [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), as it unfortunately cannot be done by a one-liner.

Available security protocols in .NET Framework 4.8:

```
SystemDefault
Ssl3
Tls
Tls11
Tls12
Tls13
```

Comment: I have investigated and updated my question accordingly. Thank you for your suggestion. It does open the avenue of adjusting what protocols are available but it must be done through the registry which I am afraid to do... I will have to investigate the risks

Comment: @hijumpkick Well, if your machine is connected to the internet, but you cannot update it, which risks could be higher than that? ;-) Keep in mind that the algorithms have to be available to be [activated via registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings). Which OS are you using exactly?